# Debug SQL in pgAdmin when SQL contains variables

Tags: sql, debugging, postgresql, pgadmin

In SQL Server I could copy sql code out of an application and paste it into SSMS, declare & assign vars that exist in the sql and run. yay great debugging scenario.

E.g. (please note I am rusty and syntax may be incorrect):

```
declare @x as varchar(10)
set @x = 'abc'
select * from sometable where somefield = @x
```

I want to do something similar with Postgres in pgAdmin (or another postgres tool, any recommendations?) where I can just drop my SQL (params & all) into something that will run against Postgres DB.

I realise you can create pgscript, but it doesn't appear to be very good, for example, if I do the equivalent of above, it doesn't put the single quotes around the value in @x, nor does it let me by doubling them up and you don't get a table out after - only text...

Currently I have a piece of SQL someone has written that has 3 unique variables in it which are used around 6 times each...

So the question is how do other people debug SQL *efficiently*, preferably in a similar fashion to my SQL Server days.

Comment: I wanted to add this as a feature request, but I couldn't as I'm not old school enough to work out how the pgAdmin mailing lists works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE commands for handling statements, which is really what we are talking about here.

For example:

```
PREPARE test AS SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = $1;
EXECUTE test ('paul');
DEALLOCATE test;
```

Perhaps not as graphical as some may like, but certainly workable.

Comment: I delete my answer suggesting to use a linked server from sql! Thanks, just a shame it they can't be named.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a shot at writing a [SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) that wraps your query. It can be something as simple as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(integer, integer) 
RETURNS integer
AS
$$
    SELECT $1 + $2;
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT my_function(1, 2);
```

I would do this instead of a PREPARE since it will be simpler to update it. Depending on how complex the function is, you might want to also look at some of the other [PL's](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang.html) in Postgres.

Comment: Not really what I was after. I don't want to have to write a function each time I need to debug SQL. Also I don't think the output would be what I require.

Comment: If all you're looking for is a way to use the variables in your query a function like that to wrap your query is really easy. What sort of output are you looking for?

Comment: the output I would get if I ran the query, or the debugger output. This definantly isn't the solution to the question - maybe there isn't an answer - I was thinking there was maybe an pgAdmin alternative I could use. I just want to paste my code into the sql window, set my vars then run it.

Comment: Ah, yeah there is no way to do that in pgAdmin that I'm aware of. Without using a PL there isnt a way to just set vars in PG.

Answer (score 0):

SQL procs are notoriously hard to debug. My lame but practical solution has been to write log  messages to a log table, like this (please excuse syntax issues):

```
create table log_message (
  log_timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  message varchar(1000)
);
```

then add lines to your stored proc like:

```
insert into log_message (message) values ("The value of x is " || @x);
```

Then after a run:

```
select * from log_message order by 1;
```

It's not pretty, but works in every DB.

Comment: I don't think their hard to debug at all. Esp in sql server. Sorry, this isn't what I'm looking for.