# What is the best database query tool for PostgreSQL on OSX?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm interested to find the best desktop database query tool for PostgreSQL. Some options are PGadmin, RazorSQL. I'm interested to know which are the best ones.

Comment: Fast, nice user experience, stable, decent feature set.

Comment: Also it would be cool if the application enabled tabs, so you could open a new tab for a new query, rather than a new window.

Answer (score 4):

After evaluating a bunch of GUI-based options for OSX I settled on [Navicat for Postgresql](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/navicat-essentials-for-postgresql/id466725643?mt=12) because to me, it has a more natural UI than pgAdmin (at least for OSX).

I find pgAdmin has a better query analysis tool though so I've got it installed as well.

Answer (score 3):

For some definition of *'best'* I humbly offer up `psql`; it is fast and easy, free, and already installed. :)

Answer (score 1):

For query only I use DbVisualiser.  It is a cross platform Java application.

Answer (score 0):

We Use PGAdmin. Not had any issues with it other than the following ([unsatisfactory answered - by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959343/debugging-sql-in-pgadmin3-when-sql-contains-variables)) question I posted a while back.

Comment: Also it is written for Postgres, whereas RazorSql is more of a generic solution - I don't know how up to date it is kept, or which advanced features it supports.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best". But I do like pgAdmin, works on any OS, not just OS X, and is for free. You could also use [OpenOffice Base](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/8-Using-OpenOffice-Base-2.3.1-with-PostgreSQL.html) to connect to your database, using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try SQL Workbench/J (Java based): http://www.sql-workbench.net